# Class as return type

Tags: java

I have an assignment in which we are to create a rock, paper, scissors game. It is specified that we have to create an abstract "Tool" class of which there are three subclasses: "ToolRock", "ToolPaper", "ToolScissors". The abstract class is supposed to have a "*+ getWeakness() : Tool*" function (written in italics).

My assumption is to make an abstract function like so:

```
public abstract Tool getWeakness();
```

The RockTool class is specified to have the function "+ getWeakness() : Tool" (not written in italics) and my thinking was to create a function which overrides the parent class:

```
@Override public ToolPaper getWeakness() { return null; }
```

What should this function return to achieve this? I can't simply "return ToolPaper;"? So how do I go about creating a function which returns which subclass of Tool it is weak against without returning a string?

[image: Here's the complete diagram:]

Comment: This is a weird design. Are you sure `Tool` in this case is not a parameter?

Comment: Okay it looks like, you simply need to `return new ToolRock()` in the case of `ToolScissor`. Your assignment is a bit confusing, but I think you are supposed to return an instance of the tool.

Comment: @Raildex Not from what I can gather from the diagram we were supplied.

Comment: Raildex is correct. You're returning a subclass of a Tool

Comment: The UML `getWeakness(): Tool` means that `getWeakness()` returns an instance of `Tool` or an instance of a subclass of `Tool`.  It does not mean that it returns a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java, classes are first class objects, so they **can** be returned just like any other object.

You will want to use generics to ensure the wrong *type* of class isn't used. Your method signature could be:

```
public abstract class Tool {
    public abstract Class<? extends Tool> getWeakness();
}
```

And your implementation would be

```
public class Rock extends Tool {
    public Class<? extends Tool> getWeakness() {
        return Paper.class;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
As others have mentioned, the design indicates that a `Tool` instance should be returned rather than a `Class`. While it would be possible for one class to return a (preferably, static) instance of the class it is weak to, this would be bad design. If the UML is your own, I would recommend changing the signature to indicate that a `Class` will be returned.

Comment: Well, the model assumes to return a `Tool` instance, not a `Class<? extends Tool>` instance.

Comment: That is true, this answer aims to resolve the primary question, but doesn't address the misunderstanding of the design. I will add an update to mention it.

Comment: This seems like the better solution rather than having to return a new object of a class. My only issue is that it doesn't exactly fit the model, but that may be the fault of the teacher.

Answer (score 2):

`@Override public ToolPaper getWeakness` does not match your UML, and there is no need to change it.

You need to return an instance of a `Tool`, not a `Class<Tool>` which you have 3 (you cannot instantiate an abstract class)

So, you'd have

```
public class ToolPaper extends Tool {
    public ToolPaper() {
        super("paper");
    } 

    @Override
    public Tool getWeakness() { return new ToolScissors(); }
}
```

You could also look into using singletons if you want to avoid new object initialization for each weakness call... Otherwise, if you're comparing equality of classes at any point, you'll want to implement the equals method

Comment: `ToolPaper getWeakness()` is valid override, you can narrow down return type.

Answer (score 0):

Your design doesn't make any sense. If you thought it up, read on and I'll explain where you've made a mental error (it's a bit tricky). If your homework book or teacher gave this assignment to you, well, read on as well, and then talk to them; they've given you an impossible assignment.

A parable:

There are many kinds of apples. There's Tessa, McIntosh, Granny Smith, Fuji, and more.

I can have a specific apple, in my hand, ready to eat. That might be *a* Granny Smith apple, but it is not 'THE Granny Smith, as a concept, in my hand'. There are many Granny Smith apples now and in the future and no one apple, or even a giant container full of all Granny Smiths on the planet, properly represents the concept 'Granny Smith'. As a concept, 'Granny Smith' is not tangible. You cannot hold it in your hand. But it is no less real. We can say:

- This specific apple is of the kind 'GrannySmith'.
- The concept 'GrannySmith' is a more specific variant of the more general concept 'Apple', which in turn is a more specific variant of the more general concept 'Fruit'.

With that in mind, in java:

```
public Apple getApple() { ... }
```

does not mean 'this method returns the concept of Apple, itself'. That would be completely pointless, if we set in stone specifically what it returns, then what point is there to ever call it?

It also does not mean 'this method returns some concept that is either Apple or some more specific take on the idea. For example, this method may return the concept of Granny Smith apples'. I can see how you might think that, but that's not what that means.

No, it means: "This method will give you a specific apple, ready to eat, in your hand". The `Apple` is merely restricting the set of valid things it may return (so, it can't give you an orange, that would not compiled).

Thus, `ToolPaper` represents the concept of paper. It is like Granny Smith. It represents all 'throws', ever made and throws that folks will ever make in the future, to represent paper.

Contrast this to `public ToolPaper getWeakness() {}` which **cannot** return 'the concept' of throwing paper. It can only return a specific throw.

Think back to the apples: `public Apple getApple()` CANNOT return 'Granny Smith, the concept'. It can only return a specific apple, which might have been created with `new GrannySmith();`. The same applies here: You must return a specific throw.

That's why you cannot simply `return ToolPaper;` - for the same reason your `getApple()` function cannot simply `return GrannySmith;` - the point of the method is to return a specific object and not a generalized concept.

There are two solutions:

1. Accept that there is a difference between 'the concept of throwing paper', as represented by the type `ToolPaper`, and a specific singular throw, as represented by `new ToolPaper()`. The method `getWeakness` is supposed to be interpreted as: "Return a newly created specific throw that would beat the specific throw represented by this object" (after all, `getWeakness` is a non-static method in an object of type Tool, thus, it is a method you invoke on a specific throw and not a generalized concept).
2. The names you chose make it feel more like `.getWeakness()` is supposed to semantically return the concept and not any specific throw, but then your return type is wrong. In that case, you need to abstract away the concept as its own type hierarchy.

The second one gets complicated and mires you in hierarchy hell, but, hey, if you want to, it would look something like this:

```
public class ToolKind {
    public ToolKind(String name, List<ToolKind> beats, List<ToolKind> isBeatenBy) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can make 'the concept' of throwing paper as an instance of a class that represents the concept of 'a legal move in a rock paper scissors style game'. With basic RPS there would only be 3 instances of this type, ever.

With this framework you can write code that can play RPS style games, and where you do not have to change any code if you want to expand your RPS game. For example, a common 'upgrade' to rock-paper-scissors is to introduce the Lizard and Spock moves.

- Scissors cuts paper, scissors decapitates lizard.
- Paper covers rock, paper disproves Spock.
- Rock crushes lizard, rock blunts scissors.
- Lizard eats paper, lizard poisons spock.
- Spock vaporizes rock, spock smashes scissors.

This seems to me to be a rather complicated construction to learn about OO concepts. Something where the relationship 'the concept of a thing' and 'a specific instance of that thing' is more obvious (such as 'the concept of granny smith' vs 'here is an apple, you can eat it, it is a granny smith apple') sound like a better idea.

NB: You may come across other answers or guides that indicate that you can always return a `Class<?>` to represent a, well, class. This is a **bad idea**, java as a language is not designed to parameterize classes like this. If you have a need to return from a method, or pass to a method, the notion of 'some RPS throw option; not any particularly specific throw, but the concept of one', then the right move is always to make a new type that then represents the concept-of-the-concept, as I have done in these snippets. In java culture these things are commonly called 'a factory', because a job you want the 'instance of a concept' to have is almost always 'please make me a new one', so if you have e.g. `class AppleKind {}` and `AppleKind grannySmith = new AppleKind("Granny Smith", ...);` to represent the concept of all granny smiths, you no doubt want AppleKind objects to have a `giveMeAnAppleOfYourKind()` method: That 'creates' one, hence, 'Factory'.

Answer (score 0):

The UML `getWeakness(): Tool` utterance expresses that the `getWeakness()` method returns an *instance* of `Tool` or of a subclass of `Tool`.

It does not mean that it returns a class.

A method that returned a class would (hypothetically) be written as something like this:

```
  getWeaknessClass(): Class
```

or maybe this:

```
  getWeaknessClass(): Class<? extends Tool>   // Java syntax ...
```

I've never encountered UML like that, and I'm not sure that it is strictly conformant to UML syntax.  However, UML is supposed to primarily be for expressing designs for humans to read, so dubious syntax is OK provided we all "know" what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

The UML specifies that `getWeakness()` should return an *instance* of a Tool class (not the class itself).

In Java, a handy way to create a class with a single instance is to use an enum, and you can create enum constants that are subclasses of the main enum class:

```
enum Tool {
    TOOL_PAPER {
        public Tool getWeakness() {
            return Tool.valueOf("TOOL_SCISSORS");
        }
     },
     TOOL_SCISSORS ...;

     abstract public Tool getWeakness();
}
```